# update specific variables in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm sure this is fairly straight forward and I'm doing something clearly wrong, but I just can't seem to get the following to work:

I've got two tables `RurUrb` and `New_Codes`

What I'd like to do is update only a few specific records from `RurUrb` with values where they match to records in `New_Codes`

```
ID  LAD18CD
3   E07000032
4   E07000224
5   E07000170
6   E07000105
7   E07000004
8   E07000200
9   E09000002
10  E09000003
etc...
```

I then have a second table which has only a handful of codes, within it are two lots of ONS codes; one is the old code, that matches some of the records in my RurUrb table, and the new code that I want to insert into the RurUrb table, replacing the old ONS Code.

```
ID  NewGeoCode  OldGeoCode
1   E07000241   E07000104
2   E07000240   E07000100
3   E06000057   E06000048
4   E06000057   E08000020
5   E07000242   E07000097
6   E07000243   E07000097
7   E07000243   E07000101
8   E08000037   E08000020
9   E07000112   E07000112
10  E07000246   E07000190
11  E06000058   E07000048
12  E06000059   E07000049
13  E06000059   E07000050
14  E07000244   E07000205
15  E07000246   E07000191
16  E06000058   E06000028
17  E06000058   E06000029
18  E06000059   E07000051
19  E06000059   E07000052
20  E07000244   E07000206
21  E07000245   E07000201
22  E07000245   E07000204
23  E06000059   E07000053
24  E10999999   E10000002
25  E06000060   E07000004
26  E06000060   E07000005
27  E06000060   E07000006
28  E06000060   E07000007
```

I think this is done using an If..Else statement, and using match within that, but I just can't get the process to only update the matching rows, leaving those that don't match alone and keep their original values.

Comment: Does `merge(RurUrb, New_Codes, by.x = 'LAD18CD', by.y = 'OldGeoCode', all.x = T)` give you what you want? You might need to take a second step where you do the column updating, but at a minimum this will provide some link between the old and new codes.

Comment: Hi, yes, thanks it helps me get the records attached. I'll work out the next stage of updating the the new columns with the data from the other column.